# Bean Validation + JAX-RS not reading custom ValidationMessages.properties

Tags: java, internationalization, jax-rs, bean-validation

I am trying to use custom messages with Bean Validation but my custom messages are not being returned by the JAX-RS resource. What am I doing wrong?

### ValidationMessages.properties

```
invoice.value.notnull=Invoice value must be informed.
```

The file is located at `src/main/resources`

[image]

### InvoiceResource.java

```
@Path("/invoice")
public class InvoiceResource {

    @POST
    public void post(@Valid InvoiceRequest request) {
        /* stuff */
    }

}
```

### InvoiceRequest.java

```
public class InvoiceRequest {

    @NotNull(message = "invoice.value.notnull")
    private Double value;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the problem was my declaration of the message in the bean param. The message ID must be forked between braces `"{ ... }"`:

```
@NotNull(message = "{invoice.value.notnull}")
```

How we get the proper JSON response with the correct message:

```
{
    "exception": null,
    "fieldViolations": [],
    "propertyViolations": [],
    "classViolations": [],
    "parameterViolations": [
        {
            "constraintType": "PARAMETER",
            "path": "post.arg0.value",
            "message": "Invoice value must be informed",
            "value": ""
        }
    ],
    "returnValueViolations": []
}
```